# Use ADB with genymotion on recent android version

Tags: android, adb, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm using Genymotion (2.8.0) to emulate android devices and my dev env is on another virtual machine from where I package and load the app using cordova and monitor logs.

I connect manually the devices with `adb connect <device_ip>`.

But I'm facing an issue with some devices, some are marked as "offline" from the guest VM. But some others are working just fine. It seems to be happening only on recent versions of android (5.1.0 and 6.0.0) while working devices are lower (4.4.4, 4.2.2) from what i tested so far.

I have already tried to use the same adb version by changing SDK settings on genymotion instead of built-in tools, but same results. Tried to uncheck and recheck USB debug on devices settings. Still the same.

Here is what i saw from the guest VM :

```
$ adb devices -l
List of devices attached
192.168.3.104:5555     device product:vbox86p model:Samsung_Galaxy_S4___4_4_4___API_19___1080x1920 device:vbox86p
192.168.3.102:5555     offline
192.168.3.103:5555     device product:vbox86p model:Samsung_Galaxy_S3___4_2_2___API_17___720x1280 device:vbox86p
```

While my host is seeing devices correctly :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools> .\adb.exe devices -l
List of devices attached
192.168.3.104:5555     device product:vbox86p model:Samsung_Galaxy_S4___4_4_4___API_19___1080x1920 device:vbox86p
192.168.3.103:5555     device product:vbox86p model:Samsung_Galaxy_S3___4_2_2___API_17___720x1280 device:vbox86p
192.168.3.102:5555     device product:vbox86p model:Samsung_Galaxy_S6___6_0_0___API_23___1440x2560 device:vbox86p
```

Doesn't matter if i launch only one at the same time or many, outcome is the same.
Since it is working on some, i don't really want to play around with network settings on VB, had a hard time finding a working setup a while ago but if that's of any help i'm using a private network between my VMs. I can correctly ping the "offline" device and it seems valid otherwise adb will not even show it as an attached device.

I'm running out of ideas here... any help would be appreciated :)
Feel free to ask more details if needed.

Comment: Does this happen at the device startup or after an hibernation? What's the OS version?

Comment: Also, you can try the command `adb disconnect`, this will disconnect/reconnect all the Genymotion launched devices.

Comment: It happens at device startup. Already tried to disconnect and then connect, kill-server and then start-server, no luck so far.